# Compiling C code without having it saved in a file

Tags: c, compilation

Inspired by this PCG challange: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61836/31033
I asked my self, if one would try to leave as few trace as possible when compiling such kind of tool (no matter of a browser or something else), is there some way (aimed for gcc/clang as this probably are the preinstalled commandline compillers in such a working enviroment) to hand over source code to the compiler as command line argument or equal mechanism, without need for the source code beeing saved as *.c file, as the user would usually do?

(ofcourse the compiler will produce temp files while compiling, but those probably won't get scanned.)

Comment: Well you could write a script that writes your source code, compiles it, then deletes it.

Comment: Why voting for close as too broad? Its a pretty concret question with just 2 answer options. 1) No it isn't possible with one of them or 2) Yes it works with gcc/clang/both, with the command named ...

Comment: @Arc676: Yeah, but that would result in a file that might be scanned or leaving a trace revealing my undesired behaving.

Comment: Not a solution, but, If you don't save the code, how will you use it in future? I mean, even if possible , this will be a one time executable code.

Comment: @SDK thats more or less, what the PCG offstory was about. Developing a small snippet which you just have to remember that you can compile it each day again so you dont have something on the disk that could reveal your behaving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least `gcc` can as it is able to read source from the standard input. You can also use Unix here string bash construction :

```
gcc -xc - << "int main() { exit(0); }"
```

or here file sh construction :

```
gcc -xc - <<MARK
int main() {
  exit(0);
}
MARK
```

----EDIT----

You can also imagine using cryptography to encode your source, uncipher the content on the fly and inject the result to the standard input of gcc, something like:

```
uncipher myfile.protected | gcc -xc -
```